# Unable to read package metadata. This may be due to missing repodata directory. Please ensure that your install tree has been correctly generated

Tags: centos, centos6

I am new for centos installation. I downloaded a minimul version of centos 6.5, around 339.7mb of size. I am trying to install this with GUI interface but I got an error after selecting the drive option, which comes after selecting the country.
 This is complete message,

```
Unable to read package metadata. This may be due to missing repodata directory. Please ensure that your install tree has been correctly generated. 

Failare:
repodata/743fec56b2af0ce8d6ec82c47a4efafc2a4d18cddfa9683f29611cb18d1a33de-primary.sqlite.bz2 from anaconda-CentOS-201311271240.i386: [Ermo 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

Sorry but I am new here, so I can't put the exact image here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe that i had this same issue and was able to solve it.

The files under the /repodata folder are missing their file extensions and are not matching their full names in the "TRANS.TBL" file, under this same dir.

Rename all the files to match what is in the "TRANS.TBL" file, then try the install over again.

Please let everyone know if this works for you.

In the past i would just put a URL in that pointed to the correct files on a server, i feel that most people take this workaround and that's why it's not as hot of an item as it should be. I hope this gets fixed in the .ISO.

Thank you,

YourFriend

Comment: I did what you said and renamed added the suffix to the files, not just the extensions, and it didn't work.

Comment: This works for me. I'll write a post to my blog soon. Thanks!

Comment: @Bradlee818: Thanks that worked like a charm. I have written few lines to automate this. One can copy paste below lines in repodata directory.

   ``for i in `cat TRANS.TBL | awk '{ print $3 }' | grep -v repomd.xml`;
    do 
    mv `echo $i | awk -F"-" '{ print $1 }'` $i -v;
    done`` I've checked this on CentOS 6.6 and CentOS 6.7.

Comment: I met this problem when installing CentOS from an USB disk. So I plug out the USB disk and change the file names on another machine, and then plug back, but retry doesn't work somehow. I must restart the host to start a fresh installation, and this time it works perfectly!

Comment: It seems some people are changing names based on "TRANS.XML" while you suggest doing it based on "TRANS.TBL". I am highly confused.

Answer (score 9):

It worked for me.
I renamed all 8 files.
i.e. 0e371b19e547b9d7a7e8acc4b8c0c7c074509d33653cfaef9e8f4fd1d62d95de
0e371b19e547b9d7a7e8acc4b8c0c7c074509d33653cfaef9e8f4fd1d62d95de-primary.sqlite.bz2

The correct file name is given in file "repomd" under folder repodata
example - location href="repodata/b124f0ec5323cfee56b420906a3103f0daef656dde3f7ac8220120aa7504e57a-primary.xml.gz"

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked. You deserve to be the "accepted answer", as the other solution did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue ; 
under "repodata" directory opened "repmod" xml file 
Searched file name within repmond xml file 
Found matching strings 
Renamed 8 files as specified in .xml file 
and it worked like a charm

Thanks to "Your Friend"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Even if you manage to get past this step, you will encounter at a later point other errors related to filenames.

The root cause was using Unetbootin to create the bootable media. I switched to Rufus and everything works fine now.