# Error Unable to read package metadata.This may be due to a missing repodata directory

Tags: linux, installation

> Error Unable to read package metadata.This may be due to a missing
>   repodata directory.Please ensure that your install tree has been
>   correctly generated. Cannot retrieve repository metadata(repomd.xml)
>   for repository:CentOs. Please verify its path and try again.
>   ('custom',[_Exit installer],'Edit','_Retry'，‘_Continue’)]

This problem is different from this question:
[Unable to read package metadata. This may be due to missing repodata directory. Please ensure that your install tree has been correctly generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637068/unable-to-read-package-metadata-this-may-be-due-to-missing-repodata-directory).

Becase I verify the repodata,the file is right.