# CentOS v6.8/v6.9 installation error Unable to read package metadata. This may be due to missing repodata directory.

Tags: centos

While installing the ÇentsOS V6.8/6.9 following error came.

```
> Unable to read package metadata. This may be due to missing repodata
> directory. Please ensure that your install tree has been correctly
> generated.  Failare:
> repodata/743fec56b2af0ce8d6ec82c47a4efafc2a4d18cddfa9683f29611cb18d1a33de-primary.sqlite.bz2
> from anaconda-CentOS-201311271240.i386: [Ermo 256] No more mirrors to
> try.
```

I have taken the help from the store overflow page [stcokoverflow question answered on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637068/unable-to-read-package-metadata-this-may-be-due-to-missing-repodata-directory)  The error issue was solved but next error regarding the google fonts and its update came. following was the error.

the file-google-crosextra-carlito-fonts-1.103.0.1.20130920.el6.1.noarch.rpm cannot be opened
The system was in the inconsistent state, the internet was there, so how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the help on the internet since 3-4 days, but could not find the appropriate answer. The issue was the with installation media I am using. I was using the bootable USB created using the software UNETBOOTIN, even though I changed the CentOS v6.8 or v6.9 the same error was persist.
                          When I used the bootable USB made from RUFUS the installation was done successfully without any error. So the issue was with the bootable media we were using. So friends while installing the CentsOS especially the v6.8 or v6.9 don't use the UNETBOOTIN for making the USB bootable. Please use the RUFUS or any other. You can download the Rufus from here. [Download Rufus from here ..!](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) Thank you.